# Impala can not read built in functions after restart

Tags: impala

I have noticed that after restarting impala I ran some queries and two of them threw an error for to_timestamp() function that I have in my view. If I rerun these queries everything runs smoothly. Why is this happening? It is like impala can not read the functions in the first-run of the queries.

Comment: is it happening for manual run or auto run also not able to pick them up?

Comment: @KoushikRoy in manual run.